# How can I achieve road fighter like car collision?

Tags: java, 2d, libgdx, physics

I am making a road fighter like 2D top down racing game and I am trying to achieve road fighter like car collision but didn't get desired result.
This is my player code:

```
package tk.techackers.race.tiny.objects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Polygon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import tk.techackers.race.tiny.utils.Constants;
import tk.techackers.race.tiny.utils.Assets;

/**
 * Created by Pintu on 6/27/2017.
 */
public class Player {
    //Maths Constants
    //MATHS
    private final float ACCL = 0.046875f * 500;
    private final float DACCL = 0.5f * 200;
    private final float FRC = ACCL;
    private final float TOP = 6f * 100;
    private float xsp = 0;
    private float angle = 0;
    private float anglularVelocity = 0;
    private static float SPEED = 200f;
    public float x, y;
    private Sprite car;
    //COLLISION RECT
    private Rectangle hitBox;
    private Polygon hitBoxPoly;
    private boolean collided = false; //To Check if player is in collision
    private float collisionTimer = 0;

    public void collided(boolean collided) {
        this.collided = collided;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return hitBox.width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return hitBox.height;
    }


    private enum STEERING {
        LEFT, RIGHT, STRAIGHT
    }

    //TODO -> implement car physics
    private STEERING currentSteering;


    //Getters and Setters

    //Checks car collision with another car
    public boolean isColliding(Polygon enemyPoly) {
        return Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(hitBoxPoly, enemyPoly) ||
                Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(enemyPoly, hitBoxPoly);    
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    //Check if on same lane
    public boolean isOnSameLane(EnemyCar car) {
        //Checking if Both EnemyCar and Player car on either side
        if ((this.x < (Constants.ROAD_X + Constants.ROAD_WIDTH) / 2 && car.getX() < (Constants.ROAD_X + Constants.ROAD_WIDTH) / 2)
                || (this.x > (Constants.ROAD_X + Constants.ROAD_WIDTH) / 2 && car.getX() > (Constants.ROAD_X + Constants.ROAD_WIDTH) / 2))

            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Player() {
        x = Constants.WORLD_WIDTH / 4;
        y = Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT / 4;
        car = new Sprite(Assets.carAtlas.findRegion("Car"));
        //set origin to center for rotation
        car.setOriginCenter();
        currentSteering = STEERING.STRAIGHT;
        //Prototype HitBox
        hitBox = car.getBoundingRectangle();
        //Real Polygon HitBox
        hitBoxPoly = new Polygon(new float[]{hitBox.x, hitBox.y,
                hitBox.x, hitBox.y + hitBox.height,
                hitBox.x + hitBox.width, hitBox.y + hitBox.height,
                hitBox.x + hitBox.width, hitBox.y});
        //for rotation
        hitBoxPoly.setOrigin(hitBox.width / 2, hitBox.height / 2);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {

        switch (currentSteering) {
            case LEFT:
                //set car rotation to 10
                car.setRotation(10);
                hitBoxPoly.setRotation(10);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                car.setRotation(-10);
                hitBoxPoly.setRotation(-10);
                break;
            case STRAIGHT:
                car.setRotation(0);
                hitBoxPoly.setRotation(0);
                break;
        }

        //Changing position with speed dx = dv/dt
        setPosition(x, y);
    }

    private void updateCollisionRect() {
        hitBoxPoly.setPosition(car.getX(), car.getY());
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        //batch.draw(car, x, y);
        car.draw(batch); 
    }

    public void drawDebug(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer) {
        //shapeRenderer.rect(hitBoxPoly.getX(), hitBoxPoly.getY(), hitBox.width, hitBox.height);
        shapeRenderer.polygon(hitBoxPoly.getTransformedVertices());
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        car.setPosition(x, y);
        updateCollisionRect();
    }

    public void turnLeft(float delta) {
        //TODO -> PROTOTYPE    

        x -= SPEED * delta;
        //currentSteering = STEERING.LEFT;
    }

    public void turnRight(float delta) {

        x += SPEED * delta;
//        currentSteering = STEERING.RIGHT    
    }

    public void turnStraight(float delta) {
        currentSteering = STEERING.STRAIGHT;
    }

    public Polygon getHitBox() {
        return hitBoxPoly;
    }
}
```

and I am checking collision like this in Game World:

```
 if (p1.isColliding(enemyHitBox)) {
            //Stop from overlapping
            if (playerHitBox.getX() > enemyHitBox.getX()) {//RIGHT COLLISION
                p1.setPosition(car.getX() + car.getWidth(), p1.getY());
                p1.collided(true);

            } else if (playerHitBox.getX() + p1.getWidth() < enemyHitBox.getX() + car.getWidth()) { //LEFT COLLISION
                p1.setPosition(car.getX() - car.getWidth(), p1.getY());
            } else if (playerHitBox.getY() + p1.getHeight() < enemyHitBox.getY()+car.getHeight()) {
                p1.setPosition(p1.getX(), car.getY());
            }
        }
```

It just keep them from overlapping.
This a screenshot from game:
[image]

Something like this I want, player should spin a bit and then stop
[image]

I am not using Box2D,its just all vector maths. If you can provide pseudo code it'll be helpful.Thanks in Advance.